# "Sorting" a Template Field in a Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, gridview

Basically i am having a problem sorting my code so that the icons sort in a order , it's not like the "sortexpression" or ' Enable Sorting ' as these don't work for me as it comes up with ' Error: Invalid Column Name ' because I am not actually using anything from a SQLDatabase.

So I ask you , the community is there any other way in which I could possibly sort this field in VB or ASP so that when i click the column name ( maybe it should be headertext? )  ' State ' it sorts it so that all the Icons appear group up in a order. Here is the snippet of code causing me problems.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State" ItemStyle-Width="80px">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="imgFlag" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="20px" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="~\icons\actn006.gif" Visible="False" />
        <asp:Image ID="imgFlag2" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="20px" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="~\icons\actn005.gif" Visible="False" />
        <asp:Image ID="imgFlag21" runat="server" Height="20px" ImageUrl="~/icons/Gtm.gif" Visible="False" Width="20px" />
        <asp:Image ID="imgFlag22" runat="server" Height="20px" ImageUrl="~/icons/Otm.gif" Visible="False" Width="20px" />
        <asp:Image ID="imgFlag23" runat="server" Height="20px" ImageUrl="~/icons/Rtm.gif" Visible="False" Width="20px" />
        <asp:Image ID="imgFlag3" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="20px" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="~\icons\actn000.gif" Visible="False" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Width="80px"></ItemStyle>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Thank you for your suggestion in advance , please make them clear as my coding interpretation is not fantastic as I am still learning.

Comment: How you are populating the GridView? Can you post the code?

Comment: Populating the GridView? You mean via a SQLDatasource? I just explained that the gridview is a SQLdatasource but this field is not , it just holds the Icons.

Comment: How are the icons being populated into the Grid?